# Сломался bs4. Ошибка при парсинге сайта

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, request

Пожалуйста, помогите!
Есть сайт:

```
https://ramenskoye.ru/novosti/
```

Есть код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

with open("index.html") as file:
    src = file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")

links = soup.find_all("div", class_="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6")
for item in links:
    all_links = item.find("div", class_="entry-header").find("h3").find("a").get("href")
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/pythonProject7/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/pythonProject7/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 250, in __init__
    raise FeatureNotFound(
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Что написано в ошибке?

Comment: Я добавил выше ошибку

Comment: @Сергей Кох пишет что библиотека парсера не установлена...а она установлена.......

Comment: У меня ваш код работает. Нужны дополнительные данные.

Comment: @Сергей Кох Странно...я сейчас скопировал другой, рабочий код в новый проект....и он выдал те же ошибки....переустановка библов тоже ничего не дала....

Comment: Я скопировал этот код и вставил в директорию рабочего парсера и он сработал.....кто даст объяснение такому поведению???
Кто то сглазил? 

Comment: порча на новые проекты походу....
Люди добрые есть мысли? Я даже мак перезагрузил....на винде помогало...тут нет

Comment: У тебя не установлен `lxml`. `pip install lxml`